# Why does code does not work after adding bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that consist of 2 list `Total Fruits and Random Fruits` with a `Show more/less button` the code works perfectly fine when i remove the `BootStrap links` but after i add it in i'm not sure why my codes completely doesn't work.

Am i making a mistake or something in my code because i have really no idea why it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```js
var redpill = {};
var greenpill = {};
var randompill = {};


var key = "Red Fruits";
redpill[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon','Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon','Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
greenpill[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
randompill[key3] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

function redraw() {
  var combineString = '';
  $.each(redpill[key], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + redpill[key][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  $.each(greenpill[key2], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv greenpill class">' + greenpill[key2][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  var randomString = '';
  $.each(randompill[key3], function(index) {
    randomString += ('<div class="pilldiv randompill class">' + randompill[key3][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.randomclass').html(randomString);
}

function adjustHeight(){
 defHeight = $('#leftpanel').height()
 $wrap.animate({
   height: defHeight
  }, "normal");
}

function listener() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#suggestid div", function() {
      data = this.innerHTML;
      $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + greenpill[key2].length);
      var element = $(this).detach();
      $('#currentid').prepend('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
      
      adjustHeight()
      
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', 'div.new-green-fruit', function() {
    data2 = this.innerHTML;
    $(this).detach();
    var element2 = $(this).detach();
    $('#suggestid').prepend('<div class="pilldiv randompill class" >' + element2.html() + '</div>');
    
    adjustHeight()
    
  });
}
redraw();
listener();

  var slideHeight = 200;
  var defHeight
  var $wrap
  $(".container").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $wrap = $this.children(".wrapper");
    defHeight = $wrap.height();
    if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
      var $readMore = $this.find(".read-more");
      $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
      $readMore.append("<a href='#'>Show More</a>");
      $readMore.children("a").bind("click", function (event) {
        var curHeight = $wrap.height();
        if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
          $wrap.animate({
            height: defHeight
          }, "normal");
          $(this).text("Show Less");
          $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeOut();
        } else {
          $wrap.animate({
            height: slideHeight
          }, "normal");
          $(this).text("Show More");
          $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
        }
        return false;
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
.pilldiv {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: Black;
  margin: 2px;
}

.randompill:after {
  content: "\002B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.new-green-fruit:after {
  content: "\292B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor: default;
}

.greenpill {
  background-color: SpringGreen;
  cursor: default;
}

.randompill {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.panel {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.new-green-fruit {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#leftpanel{
  float:left;
  width:calc(50% - 5px);
  background-color:#f2f2f2;"
}
#rightpanel{
  float:right;
  width:calc(50% - 5px);
  background-color:#f2f2f2;"
}
.container{
  display: table;
     max-height: 100%;
     width: 85%;
     background-color:white;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top:25px;    
}

.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;
}

.gradient {
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    background:url(http://spoonfedproject.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/jquer-slide/images/bg-gradient.png) repeat-x;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

.read-more {
    background:#fff;
    color:#333;
    padding:5px;
}

.read-more a {
    padding-right:22px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.read-more a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id=leftpanel>
        <h3 class="class center">Total Fruits</h3>
        <div id="currentid" class="combineclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
  
        <div class="gradient"></div>
      </div>
  
      <div id="rightpanel">
        <h3 class="class center">Random Fruits</h3>
        <div id="suggestid" class="randomclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
  
        <div class="gradient"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="read-more"> </div>
  </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see in your console what erorr you have...\

Comment: @לבנימלכה thats the problem theres no error

Comment: but it works perfect when i run it(click on random fruit and it over to total)

Comment: @לבנימלכה But thats not how its suppose to work im suppose to be able to click on the show more button and it will open the lists

Comment: Suggest you use your browser’s dev tools to figure out a) what styles on the relevant elements might be different to begin with after you added bootstrap, and b) if there is any differences in what properties are _changed_ when you click the Show More link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your .wrapper class to have box sizing

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
    -moz-box-sizing: initial;
    box-sizing: initial;
}
```

you must specify your class because bootstrap's css adds this, so defining your class .wrapper with box sizing will override this wildcard:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

working example: https://codepen.io/classicmatsuo/pen/dKQwLO